# Reader Monad in Haskell. Where is the reader passed as argument?

Tags: haskell, monads

On this monad reader example:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

tom :: Reader String String
tom = do
    env <- ask -- gives you the environment which in this case is a String
    return (env ++ " This is Tom.")

jerry :: Reader String String
jerry = do
  env <- ask
  return (env ++ " This is Jerry.")

tomAndJerry :: Reader String String
tomAndJerry = do
    t <- tom
    j <- jerry
    return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)

runJerryRun :: String
runJerryRun = (runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"
```

we can read the ˋdoˋ notation as

```
tomAndJerry = tom >>= \t -> ...
```

where ultimately you get a String back. Ok, so, basically ˋ(runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"ˋ is a reader such that ˋaskˋ gives ˋWho is this?ˋ. However, ˋtomˋ has no argument names. How is ask able to run?

Can I think of ˋtom :: Reader String Stringˋ as something like C++ generics where ˋReaderˋ is bound to some static class in compile time, which always produces "Who is this?" when you call ask  on it? Because as far as I know, ˋaskˋ is something that takes a ˋReader String Stringˋ and it's not explicitly getting it anywhere as an argument.

I know that it gets the context somehow, but I'm intersted in how it happens in the language itself.

I didn't try anything as it's not a problem itself

Comment: "However, ˋtomˋ has no argument names. How is ask able to run?". I'm not really following?

Comment: The part about thinking of it like C++ generics is actually way more complicated than what's actually going on. `Reader String String` is just a wrapper around a value of type `String -> String`.

Comment: @DavidYoung but the argument Reader String String has no name, thus it's not being used. In C++ with a Reader implementing static ask whcih returns " How is this?" , it would make sense

Comment: Why does an argument have to have a name to be used?  It's generally possible in Haskell to make almost _any_ function [without naming any of its arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming).

Comment: @MafaldoReliedo `ask` is a value of type `Reader e e` (ignoring a bit of generality that is not necessary to address here). This means that it is, ultimately, just a function of type `e -> e`. The other key part here is `(>>=)`. If we specialize that to `Reader`, then `(>>=)` "ultimately" has the type `(e -> a) -> (a -> e -> b) -> e -> b`, where `e` is our environment type. There is no magic happening (other than `do` notation being translated into applications of `>>=`, as you mention in the question). And `return` ultimately has type `a -> (e -> a)`. I'm just removing the `Reader` wrappers.

Comment: It might be helpful to try and implement your own versions of those three functions that have those types (giving them new names, so they don't conflict with the existing ones). Then, you can translate the code from your question to code that uses those newly defined functions. This is all that is needed to get that to work. There's no additional language feature involved. Just the `do` notation desugaring that you mention and then just some regular, plain old functions.

Comment: I would recommend that you forget everything you know about C++ or other languages, and not try to apply your existing mental model of computation to Haskell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A thing of type `Reader r a` is, in reality, not a value of type `a`, but a *function* of type `r -> a` that takes an `r` environment and produces a value of type `a`. Check out how many of your questions go away if I make this simple substitution in your code:

```
-- skip all imports, so we can use our own ask implementation

ask :: String -> String
ask s = s

tom :: String -> String
tom = do
    env <- ask -- gives you the environment which in this case is a String
    return (env ++ " This is Tom.")

jerry :: String -> String
jerry = do
  env <- ask
  return (env ++ " This is Jerry.")

tomAndJerry :: String -> String
tomAndJerry = do
    t <- tom
    j <- jerry
    return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)
```

Where does `ask` get its environment from? Well, it's a function, and it takes the environment as a parameter, that's where! Same for `tom`: it gets its environment passed to it as an argument.

Well, you may say, but `tom = do {- ... -}` doesn't *look* like a function that takes an argument. After all, there's no argument there on the left of the `=` sign!

You're right. It doesn't *look* like a function to a traditional imperative programmer. Nevertheless, it is. Don't worry... you'll get used to it over time! Just to give a really stupid example:

```
f = (+)
```

Although this doesn't *look* like a function (it doesn't have arguments to the left of the `=` sign), it is a function. It is exactly the same function as `(+)` is. The very similar definitions `f x y = x + y` or `f x y = (+) x y`, which look more like a function, mean almost exactly the same thing. A slightly less stupid example:

```
g = if somethingComplicated then (+) else (*)
```

Functions are simply objects that you can pass around, store in variables, return as the result of complicated calculations, etc. They don't always need to name their arguments to be a function!

Now let's walk through your post a bit.

> Ok, so, basically `(runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"` is a reader such that `ask` gives `Who is this?`.

I don't like this phrasing. It is just `tomAndJerry` that is a reader; the fuller phrase `(runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"` is a `String`, not a reader.

> However, `tom` has no argument names. How is `ask` able to run?

There isn't any named argument, but there is still an argument.

> Can I think of `tom :: Reader String String` as something like C++ generics where `Reader` is bound to some static class in compile time, which always produces `"Who is this?"` when you call ask on it?

Definitely not. `ask` is not a thing you can pass a `Reader` argument to; it is already a `Reader` action all by itself. You can't call `ask` on `tom`. You *can* think of `tom :: Reader String String` as something like `tom :: String -> String`. You can also think of `ask` as something like `ask :: String -> String` that can be used during the implementation of `tom` if you want (but no obligation).

> Because as far as I know, `ask` is something that takes a `Reader String String` and it's not explicitly getting it anywhere as an argument.

No. See previous point. `ask` *is* a `Reader String String`, it doesn't take one.

Answer (score 2):

> Because as far as I know, `ask` is something that takes a `Reader String String` and it's not explicitly getting it anywhere as an argument.

A common misconception in Haskell about monads is that monads are actions that run instantly. They are not, especially for a `State`, it is a bit misleading, a `State Int` is *not* something with a state, a `State Int` describes *changes* in `State`, and you can then link these changes together, which is essentially what such monads do.

For the same reason `Reader String String` is not something that reads from an environment. It basically is a "procedure" object, like a delegate for example in C#, that you can then invoke with the right parameters.

In this specific case, a `Reader` object can only be turned into something that "runs" with the right parameter, and that is in this case the initial environment, and the [**`runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:runReader) does that, and thus guarantees that you pass an `r`.

A simple example is for example `State`, where `State` is defined as:

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))
```

a `State` is thus basically a function that maps a state `s` to a 2-tuple with a (possibly) different state and a return value.

Now we can combine two states with:

```
combine :: State s a1 -> State s a2 -> State s a2
combine (State f1) (State f2) = State (\s -> let (s', _) = f1 s in f2 s')
```

so here we construct a new `State` object where we map a state first to a new state `s'` by letting the first function run, and then pass that new state to the second function.

Note that our combine function (which is essentially what `>>` does), does not *run* any of the two, it just constructs a function that will run.

Now if we want to run the `State` object, we need an initial state, so the `runState` will look like:

```
runState :: State s a -> s -> a
runState (State f) s = let (_, a) = f s in a
```

so we can first combine all sorts of `State` objects that are functions and that take a state as parameter and return a (possibly) different state. We combined it into a single function that takes the initial state, and passes each time the state to the next substep, and we can then call that function with the initial state to get the result.

So here a `get` would look like:

```
get :: State s s
get = State (\s -> (s, s))
```

where we thus return the state `s` both as the new state and the return value, but this only works if we are given a state, and this `State` object itself has *no* `State`.